# Efficient way to "broadcast" the sum of elements of two 1D arrays to a 2D array

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, array-broadcasting, numpy-einsum

Is there a more efficient way (without loops) to do this with Numpy ?:

```py
for i, x in enumerate(array1):
    for j, y in enumerate(array2):
        result[i, j] = x + y
```

I was trying to use einsum without success yet.

Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use broadcasting with an extra dimension:

```
result = array1[:,None]+array2
```